# Are there any advanced options for searching my Delicious links?

Tags: delicious

I would like to search through my Delicious links. It seems I can only filter by tags, and results are displayed across multiple pages, preventing me from using the browser's search button.  The search bar searches the global Delicious archive.

How can I search for the occurrence a given phrase in all links matching one or more my tags?

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Delicious provides a more efficient search feature. You can now join tags and words to compose a quite complex search pattern.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I never used Delicious, but am I right that the URL of the page with the pages tagged by you looks like this?

`http://www.delicious.com/tag/[username]/`

In that case you could use Google to search through all of them, try googling

`[some keywords] site:http://www.delicious.com/tag/[username]`

Comment: Username before the tag, but it appears to not work. Even `inurl:` doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, ok, that's sad. Sorry I couldn't help.